# Is there a constraint on the sum of the type-I & type II error probabilities?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, mathematical-statistics, p-value, type-i-and-ii-errors

Is it true that if $H_0$ and $H_a$ are complementary hypotheses of the Binomial trial, i.e., the negation of $H_0$ is $H_a$ **then** the type-I error $\alpha$ plus type-II error $\beta$ **equals** 1? Or is that sum **always** less then 1, or can it be sometimes even greater then 1?

Comment: If you mean probability of the errors, then no. Type 1 error and Type 2 error are not complementary events in general.

Comment: OK. Is that sum **always** less then 1, or can it be sometimes even greater then 1?

Comment: Please mention 'that sum' of the *probabilities* if that's what you mean, instead of the sum of the two errors.

Comment: I really mean $\alpha+\beta$ as usually denoted these two errors. $\alpha$ is the probability that we reject $H_0$ if $H_0$ is true and the other one accept $H_0$ if $H_1$ is true.

Comment: Okay. But that's not what your post says - that's what I am saying.

Comment: The post says: if $H_0$ and $H_a$ are complementary **then** $\alpha+\beta=1$, exactly as in my last comment.

Comment: Could you provide an example of what type of situation you envisage the negation of the null necessitating the acceptance of the alternative? The popularity of testing against the null is partly that there are often many alternative hypotheses and so the null is a useful common touchstone slightly less arbitrary than one of infinite alternatives.This is not to say that what you envisage is not possible, but it is not a given so it would help to understand your thinking.

Comment: I just mean something very easy and natural such as $H_0:\mu=0$ and $H_a:\mu\neq0$. By this I mean that $H_0$ and $H_a$ are complementary.

Comment: http://web.mnstate.edu/peil/MDEV102/U3/S23/S234.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For an *arbitrarily chosen* decision rule -- meaning that the decision rule can be anything that you make up just for the heck of it, it doesn't need to be sensible in any sense of the word -- the *arithmetic sum* of the Type I and Type II error probabilities can be any number in $[0,2]$ as the answer by @Bjorn points out.

Example 1: The observation $X$ always has positive value when $H_0$ is true and always has negative value when $H_a$ is true.  The decision rule is

$$X \begin{array}{c}H_0\\\gtrless\\{H_a}\end{array} 0$$

leading to both the Type I and Type II error probabilities having value $0$ and so their sum is also $0$.

Example 2: As in Example 1, the observation $X$ always has positive value when $H_0$ is true and always has negative value when $H_a$ is true.  But now the decision rule is

$$X \begin{array}{c}  H_a\\\gtrless\\{H_0}\end{array} 0$$

which is exactly bass ackwards from the decision rule in Example 1 (Hey, I said upfront that we are going to consider *arbitrary* decision rules, not necessarily only sensible ones!!).  Now, since the OP asks in a comment for an explanation of my assertion (in a previous version of this answer) that "both the Type I and Type II error probabilities have value $1$ and so their sum is $2$.", here goes.

> If the null hypothesis is true, then in our model, the observation $X$ is *always* a positive number. But the decision rule is that whenever the observation has positive value, we are going to *reject the null hypothesis.* Continuing to remember that the null hypothesis is true, we see that our decision rule tells us to *always* reject the null hypothesis (when it is true).  So, what is the *probability* that we reject the null hypothesis when in fact the null hypothesis is true? $100\%$, right? A similar argument applies to the Type II error probability.  If the null hypothesis is actually false, the observation must have negative value in our model. But the decision rule perversely insists that we must *refuse to reject the null* when the observation has negative value which happens only when the null hypothesis is false. So, the *probability* of *failing to reject the null hypothesis when in fact the null hypothesis is false* (which is what a Type II error is) must be $100\%$ too, right?
>
> Thus, both the Type I error probability and the Type II error probability have value 1 for this (admittedly contrived) example of a decision rule, and so their arithmetic sum must be 2.

Hopefully, the above is enough of a "basic computation of this fact" as the OP desires, or is necessary to resort to the Peano axioms to prove that $1+1=2$?

Example 3: The observation $X \sim U[-2,1]$ whenever $H_0$ is true while  $X \sim U[-1,2]$ whenever $H_a$ is true.  The decision rule is

$$X \begin{array}{c}H_0\\\gtrless\\{H_a}\end{array} 0$$

leading to both the Type I and Type II error probabilities having value $\frac{2}{3}$ and so their sum is $\frac 43$.

Example 4: The observation $X \sim U[-2,1]$ whenever $H_0$ is true while  $X \sim U[-1,2]$ whenever $H_a$ is true.  But now the decision rule is

$$X \begin{array}{c}H_a\\\gtrless\\{H_0}\end{array} 0$$

which is more sensible than the decision rule in Example 3, and it leads to both the Type I and Type II error probabilities having value $\frac{1}{3}$ and so their sum is $\frac 23 < 1$.

Comment: So why @AdamO says: what's wrong with his observation?                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            > P(decomposing corpse | dead) + P(looking alright | alive) > 1

Is this surprising or interesting? No. IRL one of those error probabilities will always be 0 and the other is less than or equal to 1 depending on how good or stupid the test is.

Comment: @user2925716 _You_ are the one interested in asking what the _arithmetic sum_ of the Type I and Type II error probabilities is. This arithmetic sum has _no meaning at all_ in decision making; it is a _weighted sum_ of the two error probabilities that is of interest in Bayesian decision making, and so AdamO is quite correct in his assertion that the fact that sum  that _you_ are interested in can have value greater than $1$ is neither surprising nor interesting.

Comment: Yes, but what about his argument that one of these two probabilities is always zero so it **never** can be the case that that sum is larger than $1$ ? In fact, I do not understand why your example yields number $2$, can you explain this to a beginner (me)?

Comment: @DilipSarwate: Strictly, if you're going into Bayesianism, then you don't have "probability of Type I/II error" at all, because those terms presuppose a Frequentist approach.  But then OP's question is meaningless in the first instance, so I fear we have to stay on the Frequentist side of the fence.

Comment: @user2925716: AdamO is *not* claiming that "either $\alpha =0$ or $\beta = 0$."  He is claiming (correctly) that both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are [conditional probabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability) that cannot be legally summed.

Comment: I can see now. But I'd like to see why @DilipSarwate 's second example yields number $2$. And yes, I'd like to merely see a basic computation of this fact since I'm lost now.

Answer (score 6):

Case 1: the null hypothesis is true. The type II error is 0. The type I error is less than the nominal size of the test unless the test is biased. It can be as high as 1 if the test decision is "reject the null every time".

Case 2: the null hypothesis is false. The type I error is 0. the type II error can be as high as 1 if the test decision is "do not reject the null any time".

To conflate Bayesian and frequentist terminology : you can't speak of the Pr(Type 1 error) without "conditioning" or knowing H_0 is true. A nice bit of frequentist notation is this: $P_{H_0}(\text{Event})$ to refer to probabilities of events or outcomes under the probability model where the null is true, or $P_{\theta = \theta_0}(\text{Event})$ equivalently.

If you want to be crazy and sum together probabilities that don't make sense, you can conceive of two values of $\theta \ne \theta_0$ and $\theta=\theta_0$ for which the Type 1 and Type 2 errors add to more than 1. For instance:

> P(decomposing corpse | dead) + P(looking alright | alive) > 1

Is this surprising or interesting? No. IRL one of those error probabilities will always be 0 and the other is less than or equal to 1 depending on how good or stupid the test is.

Comment: Is it so irrational to add $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and seek for their sum minimum?

Comment: Not necessarily, provided you specify (a) what the specific alternative hypothesis is at which $\beta$ will be evaluated and (b) what you are varying in order to minimize the sum.  The sum could be viewed as a proxy for a combination of losses and prior probabilities associated with two hypotheses.

Comment: @user2925716 I wouldn't. Even in the context of a power analysis, where we speculate as to the possible value(s) of $\theta$ where the alternative may hold, this "probability of error" statement only makes sense when the costs of Type 1 and Type 2 errors are the same. But they are not. I report them separately, and discuss the implications of each error.

Comment: @whuber what does it mean to "specify the alternative hypothesis"? if that is the probability model for the outcome then there is no type I error because the null is wrong. The point is being explicit about what you're comparing. You can add the probabilities together, but as I argue the sum does not represent a probability.

Comment: Adam, I'm not trying to suggest the sum represents a probability.  I am only responding constructively to the OP's query concerning "is it so irrational."  Within the limited space permitted by a comment, I was trying to suggest that such a sum can be interpreted as (proportional to) a posterior expected loss.  "Specify the alternative hypothesis" means to stipulate a specific distribution within the set known as "$H_A,$" which is usually not just one distribution.  Unless one does so, $\beta$ is undefined.

Comment: @whuber I see maybe some notation like $\beta_{\theta = \theta_1}$ + $\alpha_{\theta=\theta_0}$ could clear things up.

Comment: That looks about right.  I hope it's apparent I'm not disagreeing with you at all; I was only trying to salvage something positive out of a possible misconception on the OP's part.

Answer (score 3):

It is true that with a standard hypothesis test you either reject the null hypothesis or you do not. I.e. type II error + power = 1 under $H_A$ and non-rejection probability + type I error = 1 under $H_0$.

However, the statement the way you phrase it is not true. Type I and type II errors cannot happen under the same scenario within the traditional frequentist hypothesis testing paradigm. I.e. either $H_0$ is true, in which can you can either wrongly reject (type I error) or not reject the null hypothesis, or $H_a$ is true, in which case you can either correctly reject $H_0$ (how often you do this on average is the power) or wrongly not reject (type II error).

Comment: Please see the last added line in the question.

Comment: Regarding the last line: The sum can be any number in (0, 2). It even depends on where exactly you are within $H_A$.

Comment: In the other answer they've just proved that the sum $\alpha+\beta$ is in $[0,1]$...

Comment: It's unclear to which answer you refer--I cannot find any such proof.